# Facebook JS - FB.api() only posts message, not media attachment

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to the active users wall with a mp3 attachment. It works fine from 
Facebook's Test Console (see below), but when I call it from my mobile app, It only posts the message. What am I missing here :(

Facebook's Test Console: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Here is my JS...

Login

```
            FB.login(
               function(response) {
                  if (response.authResponse) {
                       alert('logged in');
                  } else {
                       alert('not logged in');
                  }
               },{ scope: "email,user_likes,publish_stream,offline_access" } //added offline_access to see if that was the problem
            );
```

Post to wall with attachment

```
            var attachment = {
                    'message': 'testing',
                    'attachment': {'media': [{
                        'type': 'mp3',
                        'src': 'http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3',
                        'title': 'Test Title',
                        'artist': 'My Artist',
                        'album': 'My Album' }]}
            };

            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', attachment, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert(response.error.message);
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var attachment = {
                'message': 'testing',
                'source': 'http://www.looptvandfilm.com/blog/Radiohead%20-%20In%20Rainbows/01%20-%20Radiohead%20-%2015%20Step.MP3'
        };
```

This will post the mp3 to your feed allowing a user to click a play button inline.  See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/aggJc/1/

As you will note, that when you `POST` data to the Graph API, the formatting is different than when you `GET` the same object back.  Posting is kinda shorthand notation version and the Getting is the long hand.

Comment: Your code fixed it! Thanks man, I really appreciate it. What is the difference between using 'source' and 'attachment'?

Comment: how would i put the sound title, artist, description?

Comment: Create an html web page for that mp3 that is open graph compliant.  See http://ogp.me for information.